# Constructing shell command including php variables

Tags: php, shell-exec

When this shell_exec command runs within my function, only the first url parameter is passed to the receiving php file. I suspect I am not constructing the command correctly.

```
shell_exec("curl https://inklines.art/process_emails.php?url=" . $full_site_url . "&domain=" . $domain . "&site=" . $site_title . "&title=" . $title . "&permalink=" . $permalink);
```

How should the command be constructed to pass all the variables?

Thanks much!

Comment: When it is only the curl command. Maybe you want use the [php curl functions](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-init.php) for that.

Comment: Maybe you need to screen & somehow, eg. \\\& for unix shell or better use http://php.net/escapeshellcmd

Comment: Make sure you secure your code or people may inject commands. I really recommend what @Sysix said